# Custom Google Ads UI Using API

Tags: api, user-interface, customization, ads

I want to build a simple UI that surfaces a subset of the functionality of Google Ads UI by using the Google Ads API. Is there an example that shows how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such thing, however there is a lot of examples on HOW to use the Google Ads API, and as a developer it's up to you how you want to turn that into a UI.

After all, WHAT you use the API for is entirely up to you, i.e. it is your design. Making the UI is a separate task from accessing the API, so a tutorial on how to design a UI is separate from how to access the API.

You can read about the Google Ads API here, and it's littered with examples. Warning, it has a pretty high technical level and just getting OAuth setup can prove to be a major hassle. Good Luck.

[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start)